# How I can & a big number in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use operation "&" on binary values in a dataframe. It's ok for number smaller than 20 digit, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1234567890123456789,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]})
df[df['a']&2==2]

Out[107]: 
   a  b
1  2  5
2  3  6

df['a']&2
Out[108]: 
0    0
1    2
2    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

But for number bigger than 19 digit I got this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[12345678901234567890,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]})
df[df['a']&2==2]

Out[109]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []

df['a']&2
Out[110]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  Numbers that large are going to be too big to fit into any standardized datatype, which means you can't use them with numpy at all.  (Pandas will handle them, but only as Python objects, without any numpy speed gains.)

Comment: @BrenBarn: I made some association rules, I save them as a binary pattern, then I want to & them with pattern of each test record, if result equal to pattern of association rule so record met conditions and ...

Comment: Okay.  Just be aware that if you have a lot of data of that size, your operations may become very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by doing `df.a.values & 2`, which bypasses pandas overloading and works on the underlying Python types.

The difference is because your bigger number is too big to fit into a 64-bit signed integer type (`np.int64`), so pandas makes your column of dtype `object`.  On object columns, `&` does logical operations, not bitwise operations.

You can get a series using unsigned ints this way:

```
>>> bigNums = pandas.Series([12345678901234567890,2,3], dtype=np.uint64)
>>> bigNums & 2
0    2
1    2
2    2
dtype: uint64
```

But apparently you can't create a DataFrame with a uint64 column, because [uint64 isn't fully supported in pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9506).  Even if you could, you would eventually hit the same problem if you used an integer too big for uint64.

Comment: My number is bigger than 100 digit.

Comment: @parvij: Then you're probably not going to be able to do bitwise operations on it in numpy.  A 100-digit number would require over 300 bits, and I don't know of any such datatype, certainly not in numpy.

Comment: This(https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) says & is a bitwise operations! Am I wrong?

Comment: @parvij: It's a bitwise operator *on the builtin Python types*.  Classes can overload operators to do whatever they want.  Pandas overloads `&` to do logical operations if the column has dtype object.  Your column has dtype object because your number is too big for a 64-bit int, as I said in my answer.

Comment: @parvij: I edited my answer to show that you can maybe get what you want by doing `df.a.values & 2`.